# How to handle CTRL+PLUS key across browsers?

Tags: javascript, keypress, keydown, preventdefault

I try to prevent the default zoom event and trigger a function instead.

I managed to do it for the default save event (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) across browsers:

```
document.documentElement.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  var keynum;
  if (window.event) {
    keynum = e.keyCode;
  } else if (e.which) {
    keynum = e.which;
    if (e.ctrlKey) {
      switch (String.fromCharCode(keynum)) {
        case 'S':
          console.log('CTRL S pressed');
          e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : (e.returnValue = false);
          break;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NjRbaa?editors=1010

However, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> seems more tricky since there is no cross browser `keyCode` for the "`+`" sign. I tried to use `keypress` instead of `keydown` but then the default isn't prevented in Chrome and IE.

Comment: Well, the function at the moment prints `CTRL S pressed` in the console. :) But the real app has a zoom function that is triggered. But I have no minimal example of it.

Comment: FYI `keyCode` is deprecated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode. You can use `key` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key and just check for '+'.

Comment: And you are absolute certain that your own zoom function is better than the one that is already provided in the browser and tailored for the different systems? Because if not, you will cripple the browser experience of your users.

Comment: Thanks. Isn't it a bit risky to use it already? It's just in the working draft so far.

Comment: @str: Yes, pretty sure. It's a function of a drawing app that zooms only certain elements.

Comment: And what if I cannot read the part that is not being zoomed?

Comment: Well, you use the menu of your browser.

Comment: See, you cripple the user experience. Why don't you use another keystroke for zooming only a certain area?

Comment: It's a trade-off. People are familiar with the CTRL and PLUS key combination not only from browsers but from other apps as well. So when creating an app in a web browser one faces a dilemma: should one use a key combination that users are already familiar with so they don't have to remember new ones or leave the browsers defaults in place. But many apps override the browsers default. See for example the codepen website when you press CTRL S. It is just that users when using the app start to expect other behavior. But I agree it is a trade-off.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys Try this :)

```
$(document).on('keydown', null, 'ctrl+s', fn);
```

Comment: Thanks. I am not using jQuery though and would prefer a vanilla javascript solution. But that brings me to the idea that it might be worth looking at the jQuery source at this point.

Comment: It's only dependant on a couple of jQuery methods https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys/blob/master/jquery.hotkeys.js, a small refactor and you're there!